# How to remove parent arrays and just keep the children?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here's the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John Snow
                    [id] => 2
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Arya Stark
                    [id] => 3
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Tyrion Lannister 
                    [id] => 7
                )
        )
)
```

How can I convert the above array to:

```
Array
(
    [2] => John Snow
    [3] => Arya Stark
    [7] => Tyrion Lannister
)
```

Of course this is just a small sample. I can accomplish this with 3 foreach loops, but that seems unnecessary, is there a php function that can assist with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$arr = [...];
$ans = [];
foreach($arr as $r){
    $ans[$r[0]['id']] = $r[0]['name'];
}
print_r($ans);
```